# shopify post purchase extension

Tags: shopify

Hi I'am trying to test a post purchase extension.

I tried the following steps:

- registered my post purchase extension with the code provided
- Served the extension using shopify extension serve
- Installed the local app extension to firefox
- Updated the firefox extension with the ngrok url
- Tried to checkout from my development store
  -No redirect occurs to the extension and nothing in logs, checkout goes directly to thank you page

if someone experienced could make a basic guide over this topic, that wold be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.

1. For dev stores, the store needs to have checkout extensions preview enabled. You can enable it during store setup in the partners panel. During set up you will be asked what extra features you need.
2. You need to enable checkout extensions in your main app settings in the partners panel
3. You need to enable preview mode in extension panel in partners panel. (if your extension is not on the list, remember to build and deploy it)

For checkout UI extension there is an extra step:
go to Online Store -> Themes -> Customize -> Find checkout page -> in customizer click link in the "Optimize your checkout with apps, fonts, colors, and more. Customize checkout" text (IMPORTANT: this will work only on new dev stores or the stores that have checkout UI feature enabled during setup; it's hard to tell exactly) -> scroll to the bottom and add your app.

I highly recommend going through Shopify documentation and tutorials slowly step by step :)

I wasted too much time on this detail.